# Searching Columns in R shiny Datatable that has Multiple Entries

Tags: r, filter, datatable, shiny, dt

I have a datatable in R Shiny, and one of the columns, Keywords, contains multiple entries for some rows, separated by a comma. I would like these multiple entries to be individually searchable. The default search feature for datatable treats these entries as one, long, single item.

For example, row 2's value for the column Keywords is "Keyword1, Keyword2". I would like the user to be able to search for either "Keyword1" OR "Keyword2" and find row 2. Currently, the default search bar in datatable treats this entry as one item: "Keyword1, Keyword2" and only allows people to search for "Keyword1, Keyword2" as one, joint item, not two separate values.

Here is a small, reproducible example of the problem

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

## Create an example dataset with 3 rows and 1 column
dat <- matrix(c("Keyword1", "Keyword1, Keyword2", "Keyword2"), nrow = 3, ncol = 1)
colnames(dat) <- "Keywords"
dat <- data.frame(dat)

ui <- shinyUI(
  DT::dataTableOutput('ex1')
)

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  output$ex1 <- DT::renderDataTable(
     DT::datatable(dat, filter = "top")
  )
})

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Perhaps you could implement a regex search? Pass the search term as regex (perhaps as fixed) and try to find the matching term anywhere in `Keywords`.

Comment: Can you make a minimal reproducible example, when I use datatable it gives the behavior you require by default.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can try something like this:

```
keys <- c("Keyword1", "Keyword1, Keyword2", "Keyword2")
grepl(paste("Keyword1", collapse = "|"), keys)
#output
[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE

grepl(paste("Keyword2", collapse = "|"), keys)
#output
[1]  FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
```

Since I do not have any code to reproduce, I just came up with this example which you can extend to the datatable in shiny using the user inputs.

In your case you can do something like:

```
filter <- grepl(paste(input$keys, collapse = "|"), data$keywords)
```

I am assuming `keys` is the `ID` for the user input box and `keywords` is the column in the datatable `data`. You can then use `filter` to subset your data accordingly.

EDIT:
The problem, atleast with the sample dataset and assuming the same in your case, is that the column which has a filter is a `Factor`. If you convert the column to a `Character` using `as.character()`, your code will work fine. When you search for `keyword1` in the filter, it will result in only those rows that have `keyword1` in them.

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

## Create an example dataset with 3 rows and 1 column
dat <- matrix(c("Keyword1", "Keyword1, Keyword2", "Keyword2"), nrow = 3, ncol = 1)
colnames(dat) <- "Keywords"
dat <- data.frame(dat)
dat$Keywords <- as.character(dat$Keywords)

ui <- shinyUI(
  DT::dataTableOutput('ex1')
)

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  output$ex1 <- DT::renderDataTable(
    DT::datatable(dat, filter = "top")
  )
})

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: How would you integrate this with the search function built in to DT::datatable?

Comment: Having read your main question again, I realized that you wanted the search functionality within DT::datatable to look for specific strings. When I use the `Search` option on the top right corner and not the `filter`, I can just type keyword1 and it will filter out the rows containing keyword1, similarly, keyword2 in the search will result in rows containing keyword2. The problem is when you use `filter` option.

Comment: The `filter` option is more like in Excel, you can only filter based on the values in each row. However the `Search` option looks for the strings in all columns.

Comment: Just updated the solution. The problem is the column you are trying to search is a filter. Convert it to a character and it will work fine.

Comment: The only problem with converting it to a character is that now the user has to know beforehand and type in the search term. They no longer get to see a list of available options like they do when the column is a factor. Other than that this approach works well