# Searching for individual keywords in R Shiny Datatable column filter dropdown

Tags: r, datatable, shiny

The question I have is very similar to this one and builds on it: [Searching Columns in R shiny Datatable that has Multiple Entries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42398103/searching-columns-in-r-shiny-datatable-that-has-multiple-entries)

I have a datatable with a keywords column that has multiple entries in each row. It would look something like this and have presumably hundreds of entries:

```
Keywords
_________

k1, k2
-- --
k3, k1
-- --
k2
```

Currently it's a factor column which allows the user to use the column filters to browse what the available values are. The issue is that the column filter dropdown would give options such as `k1, k2`, `k3, k1`, `k2`.

I would like the filters to say `k1`, `k2`, `k3` instead. In that pre-existing question, the suggestion was to change the column to a character column and have the user manually type in what they wanted. The OP had the same issue with this that I do which is the user can no longer see what keywords are available to them in the column. Has anyone had a similar issue and found a workaround?